# How to put(move) cursor on last word on button click?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

can you please tell me how to move cursor at the end of page(work)on button click.
I am using jquery mobile.Actually i have one page having lot of data(scrolling).I need on button click the cursor should go to end of page or end word.
window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight); work my side

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internal links could work in this case. Add an anchor to the end of the page and change your button to a link and set its `href` attribute to the `name` attribute of the other anchor.

```
<a name="endofpage"></a>

<a href="#endofpage">Go to end of the page</a>
```

Comment: Hi can't understand? can you please give me example

Comment: got it..Thanks working